# question for dask output when using dask.array.map_overlap

Tags: dask

I would like to use dask.array.map_overlap to deal with the scipy interpolation function. However, I keep meeting errors that I cannot understand and hoping someone can answer this to me.

Here is the error message I have received if I want to run **.compute()**.

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1070,0) into shape (1045,0)

To resolve the issue, I started to use **.to_delayed()** to check each partition outputs, and this is what I found.

---

Following is my python code.

Step 1. Load netCDF file through Xarray, and then output to dask.array with chunk size (400,400)

```py
df = xr.open_dataset('./Brazil Sentinal2 Tile/' + data_file +'.nc')
lon, lat = df['lon'].data, df['lat'].data
slon = da.from_array(df['lon'], chunks=(400,400))
slat = da.from_array(df['lat'], chunks=(400,400))
data = da.from_array(df.isel(band=0).__xarray_dataarray_variable__.data, chunks=(400,400))
```

Step 2. declare a function for da.map_overlap use

```py
def sumsum2(lon,lat,data,  hex_res=10):
    hex_col = 'hex' + str(hex_res)
    lon_max, lon_min = lon.max(), lon.min()
    lat_max, lat_min = lat.max(), lat.min()
    
    b = box(lon_min, lat_min, lon_max, lat_max, ccw=True)
    b = transform(lambda x, y: (y, x), b)
    b = mapping(b)
    
    target_df = pd.DataFrame(h3.polyfill( b, hex_res), columns=[hex_col])    

    target_df['lat'] = target_df[hex_col].apply(lambda x: h3.h3_to_geo(x)[0])
    target_df['lon'] = target_df[hex_col].apply(lambda x: h3.h3_to_geo(x)[1])
    tlon, tlat = target_df[['lon','lat']].values.T    

    abc = lNDI(points=(lon.ravel(), lat.ravel()), 
               values= data.ravel())(tlon,tlat)
    target_df['out'] = abc
    print(np.stack([tlon, tlat, abc],axis=1).shape)
    return np.stack([tlon, tlat, abc],axis=1)
```

Step 3. Apply the da.map_overlap

```py
b = da.map_overlap(sumsum2, slon[:1200,:1200], slat[:1200,:1200], data[:1200,:1200], depth=10, trim=True, boundary=None, align_arrays=False, dtype='float64', 
                  )
```

Step 4. Using to_delayed() to test output shape

```py
print(b.to_delayed().flatten()[0].compute().shape, )
print(b.to_delayed().flatten()[1].compute().shape)
```

> (1065, 3)
> (1045, 0)
> (1090, 3)
> (1070, 0)

which is saying that the output from **da.map_overlap** is only outputting 1-D dimension ( which is (1045,0) and (1070,0) ), while in the **da.map_overlap**, the output I am preparing is 2-D dimension ( which is (1065,3) and (1090,3) ).

In addition, if I turn off the trim argument, which is

```py
c = da.map_overlap(sumsum2, 
                   slon[:1200,:1200], 
                   slat[:1200,:1200], 
                   data[:1200,:1200], 
                   depth=10,
                   trim=False,
                   boundary=None,
                   align_arrays=False,
                   dtype='float64', 
                  )

print(c.to_delayed().flatten()[0].compute().shape, )
print(c.to_delayed().flatten()[1].compute().shape)
```

The output becomes

> (1065, 3)
> (1065, 3)
> (1090, 3)
> (1090, 3)

This is saying that when `trim=True`, I cut out everything?

because...

```py
#-- print out the values 
b.to_delayed().flatten()[0].compute()[:10,:]
```

> (1065, 3)
> array([], shape=(1045, 0), dtype=float64)

while...

```py
#-- print out the values
c.to_delayed().flatten()[0].compute()[:10,:]
```

> array([[ -47.83683837,  -18.98359832, 1395.01848583],
> [ -47.8482856 ,  -18.99038681, 2663.68391094],
> [ -47.82800624,  -18.99207069, 1465.56517187],
> [ -47.81897323,  -18.97919009, 2769.91556363],
> [ -47.82066663,  -19.00712956, 1607.85927095],
> [ -47.82696896,  -18.97167714, 2110.7516765 ],
> [ -47.81562653,  -18.98302933, 2662.72112163],
> [ -47.82176881,  -18.98594465, 2201.83205114],
> [ -47.84567   ,  -18.97512514, 1283.20631652],
> [ -47.84343568,  -18.97270783, 1282.92117225]])

Any thoughts for this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I got the answer. Please let me if I am wrong.

1. I am not allowing to use **trim=True** is because I change the shape of output array (after surfing the internet, I notice that the shape of output array should be the same with the shape of input array). Since I change the shape, the dask has no idea how to deal with it so it returns the empty array to me (weird).
2. Instead of using **trim=False**, since I didn't ask cutting-out the buffer zone, it is now okay to output the return values. (although I still don't know why the dask cannot concat the chunked array, but believe is also related to shape)
3. The solution is using **delayed** function on **da.concatenate**, which is

```py
delayed(da.concatenate)([e.to_delayed().flatten()[idx] for idx in range(len(e.to_delayed().flatten()))])
```

In this case, we are not relying on the concat function in map_overlap but use our own concat to combine the outputs we want.